# R - Aggregate variables with min function and find index related to the min value

Tags: r, min

I've got a dataframe with 3 columns (ID, Position, Value).
There are several *Positions* and *Values* per *ID*. I would like to get the minimum *Value* for each *ID* and, in the same aggregate, get the position where the value is the minimum.

For instance :

```
Data <- data.frame(c("A","A","A","B","B"),c(10,2,4,1,6),c(0,5,4,3,1))

colnames(Data) <- c("ID","Position","Value")

# The result would be :
Data_min <- data.frame(c("A","B"),c(10,6),c(0,1)) 

# Aggregate function helps me getting the min value per ID : 
aggregate (Data$Value, list(Data$ID), min)
```

But I haven't found out yet how to get the *Position* related to the min.
I could use a `which` function with the min value to be looked for but I am pretty sure there is a smarter way to do it.

Comment: Is this simple example representative of the real problem? For example, is it possible that you'll have ties? (i.e minimum value found in multiple positions). How do you want that to be treated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `ave` to subset dataframe and return all rows of corresponding *Value* matches:

```
Data[Data$Value == ave(Data$Value, Data$ID, FUN=min),]

#   ID Position Value
# 1  A       10     0
# 5  B        6     1
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I didn't know the ave expression to subset dataframe. 
Filtering process works fine as well.

Comment: Great! You are welcome. And `ave()` does not subset but runs aggregations across subsets but returns same length as input. We just include it inside `df[...,]` for subsetting. And thanks for choosing base R, usually loses out to the other data wrangling packages!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
df = Data %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   summarize(Position=Position[Value==min(Value)],
             Value=min(Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to @Antonis `summarise` answer would be to approach this problem as a filtering process:

```
Data <- data.frame(c("A","A","A","B","B"),c(10,2,4,1,6),c(0,5,4,3,1))

colnames(Data) <- c("ID","Position","Value")

library(dplyr)

Data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(Value == min(Value)) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   ID   Position Value
#   <fct>    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A        10.0   0   
# 2 B         6.00  1.00
```